# Can I point to variable ranked arrays in Fortran?

Tags: pointers, fortran

Is it possible in Fortran to have a pointer that, depending on circumstances, points to an array with a different rank?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: If the example of _pointer bounds remapping_ isn't what you are after then please provide more detail on what you are after.

Comment: I basically want to use a pointer that can point to different ranked arrays and have different ranked inputs in different parts of the code. It looks like that's not possible.

Comment: Yes, the pointer will have the rank it was declared with.  It may point to things of different rank but it won't change its own rank.